Intel Wireless-AC9462 card weak wi-fi signal after switching from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
new Ubuntu user here.
Recently I've migrated from Windows and since then, my Wi-Fi signal strength declined drastically. I'm sort of lost on how can I fix this because most of the tutorials or troubleshootings focuses more on Realtek cards or "no adapter found" kind of problems. This is not the case, the adapter is being detected, only getting really poor signal. Any information I can provide to clarify the situation will be edited in as recommended. Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
